# Preventing irregular gaps with the text CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to prevent irregular gaps between my inputs and my text. How should I do this with a CSS property?

For example that my input will be placed all over that red line: 
[image]
My HTML:

```
<body>
<div>
    <p class ="LabelInput">Programme/CP/Ville       
    <input type="text" id="cp" name="cp"
           placeholder="" />
    </p>
</div>

<div class = "Typologie">
    <p class ="LabelInput">Typologie       
    <input type="checkbox" id="Studio" name="Studio" checked />
     <label for="Studio">Studio</label>

     <input type="checkbox" id="T2" name="T2" checked />
     <label for="T2">T2</label>

     <input type="checkbox" id="T3" name="T3" checked />
     <label for="T3">T3</label>

     <input type="checkbox" id="T4" name="T4" checked />
     <label for="T4">T4</label>

     <input type="checkbox" id="T5P" name="T5P" checked />
     <label for="T5P">T5P</label>
 </p>
</div>

<div class = "Type">
    <p class ="LabelInput">Type        
    <input type="checkbox" id="Appartement" name="Appartement" checked />
     <label for="Appartement">Appartement</label>

     <input type="checkbox" id="Maison" name="Maison" checked />
     <label for="Maison">Maison</label>

     <input type="checkbox" id="Commerce" name="Commerce" checked />
     <label for="Commerce">Commerce</label>

     <input type="checkbox" id="Parking" name="Parking" checked />
     <label for="Parking">Parking</label>
     </p>
</div>

<div class = "Budget">
    <p class ="LabelInput">Budget       
    <div id="slider-range"></div>
    </p>
</div>

<div class = "Livraison">
    <p class ="LabelInput">Livraison        
    <input type="text" id="cp" name="cp"
           placeholder="" />
           </p>
</div>

<div class = "Annexes">
    <p class ="LabelInput">Annexes        
    <input type="text" id="cp" name="cp"
           placeholder="" />
           </p>
</div>
```

I'm sure it is something you can do but I can't remember or find the property.

Comment: Min-width on the Label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make some adjustments to your HTML for the best results.
As `p` is not allowed to contain block-level elements, you can not put `div`s in it as seen in your Budget section.

Form the w3 site:

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).

Instead, add two `div` wrappers around your label and your content for a clean solution:

```css
.LabelInput {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.LabelContent {
  width: 69%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class = "Type">
    <div class="LabelInput">Type</div>
    <div class="LabelContent">
     <input type="checkbox" id="Appartement" name="Appartement" checked />
     <label for="Appartement">Appartement</label>

     <input type="checkbox" id="Maison" name="Maison" checked />
     <label for="Maison">Maison</label>

     <input type="checkbox" id="Commerce" name="Commerce" checked />
     <label for="Commerce">Commerce</label>

     <input type="checkbox" id="Parking" name="Parking" checked />
     <label for="Parking">Parking</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you do not want to change your html, add a wrapper element like `span` around your label and set min-width on it. That is an easy, albeit dirty solution.

```
<div class="LabelInput"><span class="myLabel">Type</span></div>

.myLabel {
    min-width: 200px //adjust as needed to size of biggest label
    display: inline-block;
}
```